# Print variable from action zend2 framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to print a variable fromm saveAction so i can see what is the value of that variable. I am learning Zend2 and i have continued where other developer stoped so i am trying to understand it better...This application is also using Doctrin.

I have this action which will save some data to database.

```
public function saveAction() {
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $logedUser = $this->getLogedUser();

    print_r($_POST);

    $shopId = (int) $this->params()->fromPost('shop_id', null);

    print_r($shopId);

    $shop = $this->getServiceLocator()
                    ->get('Catalog\Model\Shop')
                    ->getRepository()
                    ->findOneBy(array('id' => $shopId, 'user' => $logedUser->getId()));
    print_r($shop);

    return $logedUser;
    return $shop;
    return $view;
}
```

I can print values from post, and variable shopId, but `print_r($shop);` doesn't show anything. How can i see the value of shop variable?

Comment: did you set 'Catalog\Model\Shop' in Module.php getServiceConfig?

Comment: Is there a record in the shop table for that id and user?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   echo $shop->__toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may have confused you with multiple prints but i am only looking to print $shop

Comment: it shows me this error  Call to a member function __toString() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you might want to try this one:

```
print_r($this->getAllParams());
```

instead of using `$_POST`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what i am looking form. I want to print $shop variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$shop = $this->getServiceLocator()
->get('Catalog\Model\Shop')
->findOneBy(array('id' => $shopId, 'user' => $logedUser->getId()));
```

please remove ->getRepository() from your code, then you will get your result.

Comment: print_r($logedUser);
print_r($shopId);
what shows these. did you get $logedUse?

Comment: print_r($logedUser) print out very large object, i think it is because of Doctrine. print_r($shopId) prints me the value from post, which is good.

Comment: Did you get any output of $logedUser->getId().

Comment: i think you have no data in the table please check your query.

Answer (score 0):

At this point we dont know what the Service/Factory 'Catalog\Model\Shop' does. I assume it get's the Entity manager. The query looks ok to me 2. But having 3 return's is just wrong!

Your view will never have the `$shop;` nor the `$view;` variable in your `.phtml` view File. In ZF2 you can just return a Array to your view like so:

```
return array('shop' => $shop, 'logedUser' => $logedUser);
```

This will save those variables within your `save.phtml` 
in `/yourmodule/view/yourcontroller/save.phtml`

If you want to set the `.phtml` matching yourself you indeed could use the view model like you tried in your code the procedure is a litle diffrent then. It could look like this:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
            'logedUser' => $logedUser,
            'shop' => $shop,
            ));
$viewModel->setTemplate('yourmodul/yourcontroller/save');
return $this->getContainerViewModel($viewModel);
```

Once you have that you can just access your variables in the `save.phtml` template file like so:

```
<?php echo $shop->getSomething(); ?>
```

You did not show us the Shop entity but I assume it has methods like `getName()`, `__toString()` etc. You can just call these Object methods within your view.

If you still have trouble understanding the mvc concept of zf2  you might want to re-read the zf2 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show us what Catalog\Model\Shop and what query are you using for getting your data. Is there possibility that your query just getting null because it fails to get anything from database ? Do you have any kind of checks in your model to find out is your result from query good?